# onScroll is not working after React 18 upgrade

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, dom-events, react-virtualized

The onScroll callback(scrollHandler) is not getting called while scrolling. This issue is happening after we upgraded to react 18 from react 16.

**Package details**

```
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
"react-virtualized": "^9.13.0",
```

**Code snippet**

```
const TableComponent = (props) => {
  let { scrollHandler, getRow, width, height, rowCount, rowHeight, getRow } = props;

  return (
    <div
      onScroll={scrollHandler}
    >
      <AutoSizer>
        {({ width, height }) => {
          return (
            <List
              width={width}
              height={height}
              rowCount={rowCount}
              rowHeight={rowHeight}
              rowRenderer={getRow}
              columnWidth={150}
              style={{ maxHeight: maxHeight }}
            />
          );
        }}
      </AutoSizer>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I tried to directly add in the autosizer. I tried to add in the eventListener using ref to the tag. But none it worked.
Is there anyways to make onScroll work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the sandbox code you asked for:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { AutoSizer, MultiGrid } from "react-virtualized";
import styles from "./ScrollSyncExample.css";

export default () => {
  const [state] = React.useState({
    fixedColumnCount: 1,
    fixedRowCount: 1,
    scrollToColumn: 0,
    scrollToRow: 0,
  });
  const divRef = useRef(null);
  const _cellRenderer = ({ columnIndex, key, rowIndex, style }) => {
    return (
      <div className={styles.Cell} key={key} style={style}>
        {rowIndex === 0 ? (
          `Header: ${columnIndex}- ${rowIndex}`
        ) : (
          <span>{`${columnIndex} - ${rowIndex}`}</span>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  };

  const handleScroll = (scrollInfo) => {
    var scrollLeft = scrollInfo.scrollLeft;
    var scrollTop = scrollInfo.scrollTop;
    console.log("Scroll Left:", scrollLeft, "Scroll Top:", scrollTop);
    // Perform any other actions you want to do on scroll.
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <AutoSizer disableHeight>
        {({ width }) => (
          <MultiGrid
            {...state}
            cellRenderer={_cellRenderer}
            columnWidth={75}
            columnCount={50}
            enableFixedColumnScroll
            enableFixedRowScroll
            height={300}
            rowHeight={70}
            rowCount={100}
            width={width}
            hideTopRightGridScrollbar
            hideBottomLeftGridScrollbar
            hideBottomRightGridScrollbar
            onScroll={({ scrollLeft, scrollTop }) =>
              handleScroll({ scrollLeft, scrollTop })
            }
          />
        )}
      </AutoSizer>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[Sandbox sample here](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-virtualized-scroll-sync-forked-6zpl26?file=%2Fsrc%2FTableComponent.js%3A4%2C1&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clohim1ac000b356lrjdx5jap%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clohim1ab0004356lo8gruy6l%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clohim1ac0008356l1gwa1kv4%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clohim1ac000a356l7lozlf5q%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clohim1ab0004356lo8gruy6l%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clohim1ab0004356lo8gruy6l%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clohim1ab0003356ll1dgu8hp%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clohim1ab0003356ll1dgu8hp%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252FTableComponent.js%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Findex.js%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clohipvh200a6356lieccd17j%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522clohim1ac000a356l7lozlf5q%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clohim1ac0009356londz2jqf%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522start%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A3000%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clohim1ac000a356l7lozlf5q%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clohim1ac0009356londz2jqf%2522%257D%252C%2522clohim1ac0008356l1gwa1kv4%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clohim1ab0005356lyuduli7c%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522start%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clohim1ab0006356lsu2lu48x%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522build%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clohim1ab0007356lsbpw6q9z%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TERMINAL%2522%252C%2522shellId%2522%253A%2522cloe1mep7000befgd2vt399mw%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clohim1ac0008356l1gwa1kv4%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clohim1ab0005356lyuduli7c%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding  `overflow: 'scroll'` to your parent div style where onScroll prop have been set?

Comment: I changed the parent component style to `overflow: 'scroll'`. It is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can try an event listener if 'onscroll' is not working.

```
  useEffect(() => {
  const handleScroll = event => {
    console.log('hello scroll listener', event);
  };

  window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);

  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
  };
  }, []);
```

This code will add a listener to your window and trigger your 'handleScroll' function when the window is scrolled.

Comment: I tried this as suggested and I also tried like window.onscroll. but this approach is also not working.

Comment: It's not possible this snippet is working i tried it first then shared it with you

Comment: It was working in react 16 but after the react 18 upgrade same code is not working. Even I am not sure of the reason.

Comment: I tried this code on React 18, and it's working fine there. You might be doing something wrong. Please share your code so I can check what the issue might be.

Comment: Sure, I have tried a similar example in a forked repo in codesandbox. The behaviour is same.
Link for public sandbox - https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-virtualized-scroll-sync-forked-8nfhy6?file=%2Fsrc%2FTableComponent.js%3A8%2C6

Comment: I checked your CodeSandbox code and posted another answer for you. Please check it. The previous code was not working because I provided code for a window listener, but you needed a listener on the MultiGrid component. Therefore, I updated your CodeSandbox code, forked it, and shared the link below in my other answer. If you are satisfied with my code, please consider voting for my answers.